# Jenkins - pip having long shebang line: No such file or directory error

Tags: python, jenkins, virtualenv, shebang

I have a jenkins job in which I am using virtualenv and then installing some python modules (enlisted in a requirements file).

My code is pretty simple:

```
virtualenv env
source ./env/bin/activate
echo $(python --version)
echo $(which pip)
echo $(pip --version)
```

When my job runs, which python and which pip show me correct output but pip --version throws an error:

```
++ which python
/scratch/jenkins/ncs-jenkins/workspace/proj/docker/mail/tools/ici/gate/kokilla-gold/testproj-my    deploy-newchanges-20/env/bin/python


++ which pip
/scratch/jenkins/ncs-jenkins/workspace/proj/docker/mail/tools/ici/gate/kokilla-gold/testproj-my    deploy-newchanges-20/env/bin/pip

++ pip --version
/tmp/hudson2230168319717284464.sh: /scratch/jenkins/ncs-jenkins/workspace/proj/docker/mail/tools/ici/gate/kokilla-gold/testproj-my    deploy-newchanges-20/env/bin/pip: /scratch/jenkins/ncs-jenkins/workspace/proj/docker/mail/tools/ici/gate/kokilla-gold/testproj-my    deploy-newchanges-20/: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I think what's going on here is that the shebang line is greater then 127 chars and that's causing the issue. Its also referenced [here](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/596). My path is

```
PATH=/scratch/jenkins/ncs-jenkins/workspace/proj/docker/mail/tools/ici/gate/kokilla-gold/testproj-my    deploy-newchanges-20/env/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

/scratch/jenkins/ncs-jenkins/workspace/proj/docker/mail/tools/ici/gate/kokilla-gold/testproj-mydeploy-newchanges-20/env/‌​bin/pip is a text file. Here are its contents:

```
#!/scratch/jenkins/ncs-jenkins/workspace/proj/docker/mail/tools/ici/gate/kokilla-gold/testproj-mydeploy-newchanges-20/env/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

I'm not sure what I can do to change the shebang line in pip because its autogenerated and stored in my Jenkins workspace when I run virtualenv. What can I do to prevent this error?

Comment: What is the line ending: linux or windows format?

Comment: it is linux format.